# Hue output from cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV does not correspond with calculated value

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

**Why does cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV give an hue output that I do not expect? 

Why does is seem like cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV is not following its documentation?**

I've been doing some image analysis in Python using opencv. I want to convert RGB images to HSV. Then, using a mask I created earlier, I want to obtain the mean H, S, and V value for the masked part of the image. To do so, I'm using:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

mask = #some mask I've created using thresholding

filename = '...png'
BGR_img = cv2.imread(filename)                   
HSV_img = cv2.cvtColor(BGR_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mean_h, mean_s, mean_v, k = cv2.mean(HSV_img, mask)
```

I get the following output:

```
mean_h = 144.36 
mean_s = 154.34 
mean_v = 52.56
```

I want to check whether this output makes sense, so I have the following idea: obtain the mean R, mean G and mean B values for the same masked image and calculate 'by hand' what the corresponding mean H, mean S, mean V values should be. For this calculation, I follow opencv's documentation on color conversions (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor). My assumption is that the mean HSV values I calculate using the documentation, should correspond with my output from cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV (= values above). After all, the function cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV does what is stated in the documentation! My assumptions seems to be incorrect..

I used a similar method as above to obtain mean_r, mean_g, mean_b and checked with ImageJ -> analyse -> histogram if these values made sense (they did!). I got:

```
mean_r = 52.27 
mean_g = 21.30 
mean_b = 30.05
```

Then from the documentation I follow these steps (I work with 8-bit images):
[image]

To get:

```
mean_h_calculated = 171.58 
mean_s_calculated = 151.13 
mean_v_calculated = 52.3
```

Obviously mean_h does not equal mean_h_calculated. In other words, the mean hue I get from using cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV does not correspond with the value I calculate myself when using the documentation. (for s and v I can accept that there is a small difference) I expect the hue to be around 171 because the masked part of the image that I'm analysing is red.

**Why does cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV give an hue output that I do not expect? 

Why does is seem like cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV is not following its documentation?**

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

p.s. I think it has nothing to do with the scaling of hue (0-180 instead of 0-255).

Comment: do you expect that for example mean_h (which is the mean of all individual h values) is equal to h(mean_r,mean_g,mean_b)? Probably that's not the case. Can you instead try for a single pixel value like hsv(pixel(0,0))?

Comment: hue is a circular quantity. Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities "most of the usual means may not be appropriate on circular quantities. For example, the arithmetic mean of 0° and 360° is 180°, which is misleading because for most purposes 360° is the same thing as 0°"

Comment: @Micka thanks for your suggestions! I'll try for one pixel. I did expect mean_h = h(mean_r, mean_g, mean_b) because I noticed that mean_s = s(mean_r, m_g, m_b) and likewise for v. But that's then an assumption of course. Also, I input my mean_r, mean_g, m_b values on http://colorizer.org and got the values I calculated (mean_h_calculated) instead of what cv2.COLOR outputs (mean_h)...